# Problems with selecting objects from a group

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently creating my own custom group class with extended group functionality. First, I created a feature where objects in the group can be selected. The concept of the feature is:

1. Detecting the mouse point when the mouse is clicked on canvas.
2. Detecting object in group based on mouse point.
3. If an object is found in the group, activate the object.
4. If an object is not found in the group, then activate the group.
5. The active object in the group has a solid border, and the group has a dotted border.

Everything works perfectly when the group hasn't been modified. However, these problems come when the group is scaling, rotating and skewing:

1. The selection area of ​​objects in the group does not follow the actual size.
2. A solid border still shows the initial properties where the object was created, not following the rotation and scaling of the group.

For more details, you can see the image below:

[problem and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgRgH.png)

Here's the group custom class:

```
/**
 * GroupExtended class
 * @extends fabric.Group
 * @todo preserve object stacking
 * @todo fix bug object coords on group scaling
 */
var GroupExtended = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
  /**
   * Type of an object
   * @type String
   * @default
   */
  type: "group-extended",

  /**
   * When set to `false`, object's controlling borders are not rendered
   * @type Boolean
   * @default
   */
  hasBorders: true,

  /**
   * Array specifying dash pattern of an object's borders (hasBorder must be true)
   * @type Array
   * @default
   */
  borderDashArray: [5, 5],

  /**
   * Selected object
   * @type fabric.Object
   */
  _selectedObject: null,

  /**
   * Remove solid border from selected object
   */
  _removeSelectedBorder: function () {
    this.canvas.clearContext(this.canvas.contextTop);
  },

  /**
   * Show solid border from selected object
   */
  _showSelectedBorder: function () {
    this._removeSelectedBorder();
    this._selectedObject &&
      this._selectedObject._renderControls(this.canvas.contextTop, {
        hasControls: false,
      });
  },

  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param {Object} objects Group objects
   * @param {Object} [options] Options object
   * @param {Boolean} [isAlreadyGrouped] if true, objects have been grouped already.
   * @return {Object} thisArg
   */
  initialize: function (objects, options, isAlreadyGrouped) {
    this.callSuper("initialize", objects, options, isAlreadyGrouped);

    this.on({
      moving: this._showSelectedBorder,
      deselected: this._removeSelectedBorder,
    });
  },

  /**
   * Get selected object based on mouse point.
   * Return detected object or
   * most top of objects if more than one object detected in mouse point or
   * null if mouse point refer to empty area in group.
   * @param {Object} point object with "x" and "y" number values
   * @return {fabric.Object} selected object
   */
  getSelectedObjectInGroup: function (point) {
    // reset last known selected object
    this._selectedObject = null;
    this._removeSelectedBorder();

    this.forEachObject(
      function (obj) {
        var matrixPoint = obj.calcTransformMatrix();

        var center = {
          x: matrixPoint[4],
          y: matrixPoint[5],
        };

        var thisPos = {
          xStart: center.x - obj.width / 2,
          xEnd: center.x + obj.width / 2,
          yStart: center.y - obj.height / 2,
          yEnd: center.y + obj.height / 2,
        };

        if (point.x >= thisPos.xStart && point.x <= thisPos.xEnd) {
          if (point.y >= thisPos.yStart && point.y <= thisPos.yEnd) {
            this._selectedObject = obj;
            this._showSelectedBorder();
          }
        }
      }.bind(this)
    );

    return this._selectedObject;
  },
});
```

Link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/clngkusnd/pa5dzLm2/

The question is why does the selection area of selected objects **remain the same** when the object is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection area code in fabricJS does not take in account group transformation, maybe this can be fixed even if fabricJS for now has no reason to support selection in groups.
Just a note that what you achieved can be done without writing custom code to find the internal object:

https://jsfiddle.net/asturur/wg0mkjv2/3/

fabricJS supports out of the box target finding inside groups, enabling the `subTargetCheck` boolean property to `true`